# Extimate error, payment rate, continous compounded

Tags: finance, estimation

Give an estimate of the error, when the payment rate
$x_m = r P_0 \frac{(1+r/m)^{mT}}{(1+r/m)^{mT}-1}$
(compounding and repayment m times per year) ist approximated bei $x_{\infty}=\frac{r P_0* e^{rt}}{e^{rt}-1}$.

Hello everyone,

$P_0$..initial loan

$t$...time when loan has to be repaid

$r$..nominal intrest rate

$x_m/m$.. repayment per period ($x_m$ is then repayment per year)

In lecture we derive for a loan of $P_0$ with runtime t,which is continous compounded with a nomial rate of r the formula $x_{\infty}=\frac{r P_0* e^{rt}}{e^{rt}-1}$.

It´s obviously that $ \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} x_m=x_{\infty} $.

Should i estimate $|x_m-x_{\infty}|= |r P_0 \frac{(1+r/m)^{mT}}{(1+r/m)^{mT}-1} -\frac{r P_0 e^{rt}}{e^{rt}-1}|$= $r P_0|\frac{(1+r/m)^{mT}}{(1+r/m)^{mT}-1}-\frac{e^{rt}}{e^{rt}-1}|$ for fixed m? Or what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to notice that $T=t$ because both are the term of the loan.  As you say $\lim_{m \to \infty} (1+\frac rm)^{mt}=e^{rt}$, which justifies your expression for $x_m-x_\infty$.    You are asked to describe how close the left side is to the limit, presumably when $m$ is somewhat large.  You can note that both sides are $t^{th}$ powers and compare $(1+\frac rm)^{m}$ and $e^{r}$  Now you can expand $e^r$ in a Taylor series and compare with the binomial expansion of $(1+\frac rm)^{m}$.  You should be able to say something about how the approximation improves as $m$ gets larger